# ionic framework, pra quais plataformas compila ?

Tags: ionic

Pra quais plataformas o framework ionic compila ? e o resultado final é um app nativo ou é um app web que roda nas plataformas ?

Answer (score 3):

O resultado final é um aplicativo híbrido. Basicamente *webviews* rodando seu aplicativo. E as plataformas suportadas são iOS e Android.

Documentação http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/preface.html:

> With Ionic, we wanted to build an HTML5 mobile development framework
> that was focused on native or hybrid apps instead of mobile websites,
> since we felt there were great tools already for mobile website
> development. So Ionic apps aren't meant to be run in a mobile browser
> app like Chrome or Safari, but rather the low-level browser shell like
> iOS's UIWebView or Android's WebView, which are wrapped by tools like
> Cordova/PhoneGap.
>
> What is Ionic, and where does it fit?
>
> Ionic is an HTML5 mobile app development framework targeted at
> building hybrid mobile apps. Hybrid apps are essentially small
> websites running in a browser shell in an app that have access to the
> native platform layer. Hybrid apps have many benefits over pure native
> apps, specifically in terms of platform support, speed of development,
> and access to 3rd party code.